# Multiple buttons in for loop doesn't work because of the same id

Tags: html, css, django, button

So i want to build a website that has some cointainers for each object in my database and the same 2 buttons on each, "reguli" and "cumpara", everything works fine until i press the buttons. They work only for the first cointainer. My guess is that having the same id for each button of all containers, they work only as one. How could i change the id's of the buttons for each object in the database?

•EVENIMENTE•

```
<div class="feturedimage">
    <div class="row firstrow">
        <div class="col-lg-6 costumcol colborder1">
            <div class="row costumrow">
          {% for obj in events %}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 txt1colon ">
                    <div class="featurecontant">

                        <h1>{{obj.Nume}}</h1>
                      <p>"{{obj.Descriere}}"</p>
                        <h2>Price {{obj.Pret}}</h2>
                        <button id="btnRM" onclick="rmtxt()">REGULI</button>

                        <div id="readmore">
                                <p>Biletele se cumpara cu cardul
                                    nu se poate da refund
                                    distractie faina!
                                </p>



                                <button id="btnRL">READ LESS</button>
                        </div>

                        <button id="btncumpara" onclick="rmtxt()">CUMPARA</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 costumcol colborder2">
            <div class="row costumrow">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also share the function called `rmtxt`?

Comment: i use Vuejs. that place i define id ==> :id="btn" + index... so index is dynamic and i have buttons with different id

Comment: Id for each element in HTML has to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have different IDs, so you can use `obj.id‍(id="btnRM-{{obj.id}}" )` or `forloop.counter (id="btnRM-{{forloop.counter}}")` to set different `id` for each container buttons:

```
{% for obj in events %}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 txt1colon ">
        <div class="featurecontant">
          <h1>{{obj.Nume}}</h1>
          <p>"{{obj.Descriere}}"</p>
          <h2>Price {{obj.Pret}}</h2>

          <button id="btnRM-{{obj.id}}" onclick="rmtxt()">REGULI</button>
            <div id="readmore">
                <p>Biletele se cumpara cu cardul
                    nu se poate da refund
                    distractie faina!
                </p>

                <button id="btnRL">READ LESS</button>

            </div>

            <button id="btncumpara-{{obj.id}}" onclick="rmtxt()">CUMPARA</button>

        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```